How to compile for multiple architectures in a single build
GN Reference: https://github.com/o-lim/generate-ninja/blob/master/docs/cross_compiles.md
specifies cross-compilation is supported along with multi-architecture builds. How to specify the list of architectures I need the build for?
Also, doesn't it mean I need to specify multiple out directories too? How to specify this in target_cpu?

AFAIK, it only supports a single architecture.

target_cpu is just a "global" GN variable for you to use as you see fit. You assign whatever string you want to it in your toolchain, and then your build files can test the value in if statements.
To support multiple architectures, you must define one toolchain per architecture that you care about. For each toolchain, you define all of the tools required to support the toolchain (e.g. "c", "cxx", "link", etc). Then, you create targets in your build that use those toolchains.
GN has the concept of a "default" toolchain- targets built with the default toolchain will have their artifacts placed in root-level "obj" and "gen" directories under your output directory. When you build targets with other toolchains, the "obj" and "gen" directories will be in a subdirectory named after the toolchain, also under your output directory.  It's asymmetrical.
There's a little bit of information on this in the "Using GN build" presentation here: https://docs.google.com/presentation/d/15Zwb53JcncHfEwHpnG_PoIbbzQ3GQi_cpujYwbpcbZo/edit#slide=id.g127ae6eb4e_8_4
and in the GN reference manual itself here: https://gn.googlesource.com/gn/+/main/docs/reference.md#func_toolchain
